# Doctrine - Query builder - Select few column of a leftjoin

Tags: symfony, select, doctrine, left-join

I have two entities :

- NOTE : id, title, description, isPublic, user
- USER: id, email, firstname, lastname, password, salt, roles, tag

I would like to select just few columns of the user when I get all notes of my database (in order to don't get the password of the user for example)

So in the NoteRepository I have made a doctrine request like this :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n');
//Get the owner of the knowledge
$qb
    ->leftJoin('n.user', 'owner')
    ->addSelect('owner.tag as ownerTag, owner.firstname as ownerFirstname, owner.lastname as ownerLastname')
;

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

(I insist to do it with a join clause, because we can imagine more than one user like owner of the note)

And I get this following JSON response :

```
[
   {
      "0":{
         "id":6,
         "title":"A1",
         "description":"A1",
         "isPublic":false,
         "ownerTag":"#02a4c022d8",
         "ownerFirstname":"ama",
         "ownerLastname":"ama"
      }
   },
   {
      "1":{
         "id":7,
         "title":"Z1",
         "description":"Z1",
         "isPublic":false,
         "ownerTag":"#00a7bd24g8",
         "ownerFirstname":"z",
         "ownerLastname":"z"
      }
   }
]
```

But I would like this following response :

```
[
   {
      "0":{
         "id":6,
         "title":"A1",
         "description":"A1",
         "isPublic":false,
         "owner":{
            "tag":"#02a4c022d8",
            "firstname":"ama",
            "lastname":"ama"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "1":{
         "id":7,
         "title":"Z1",
         "description":"Z1",
         "isPublic":false,
         "owner":{
            "tag":"#00a7bd24g8",
            "firstname":"z",
            "lastname":"z"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

I don't know how to get it. Thank you to helping me ;)

Comment: What happens if you do `->addSelect('owner.tag, owner.firstname , owner.lastname')`

Comment: The same things I wouldn't, but with 'tag' instead of 'owner Tag' etc ...

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I found a solution. 
I need to use the clause *PARTIAL* like this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n');
//Get the owner of the knowledge
$qb
    ->leftJoin('n.user', 'owner')
    ->addSelect('PARTIAL owner.{id,tag,firstname,lastname}')
;

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/118

I'm not sure you're able to do it straight with your queryBuilder.

But you could surely do it with some PHP work on your array :)